# How to conntect those two Entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I got a few entities and relationships in my application, which work perfectly fine. But there is a relationship, which I can't get right.

Scenario: I have **Registration**s and **Professor**s. Each Registration has exactly two Professors assigned. But Professors can be assigned to multiple Registrations.

My Models:

```
public class ThesisRegistration : Entity
{
    ...
    [Required] public long FirstExaminerId { get; set; }
    public Professor FirstExaminer { get; set; }
        
    [Required] public long SecondExaminerId { get; set; }
    public Professor SecondExaminer { get; set; }

    public List<ProfessorThesisRegistration> ProfessorThesisRegistrations { get; set; }
}

public class Professor : Entity
{
    ...
    public List<ProfessorThesisRegistration> ProfessorThesisRegistrations { get; set; }
}

public class ProfessorThesisRegistration
{
    public int ProfessorId { get; set; }
    public Professor Professor { get; set; }

    public int ThesisRegistrationId { get; set; }
    public ThesisRegistration ThesisRegistration { get; set; }
}
```

Then the configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProfessorThesisRegistration>().HasKey(i => new {i.ProfessorId, i.ThesisRegistrationId});
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProfessorThesisRegistration>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.Professor)
        .WithMany(f => f.ProfessorThesisRegistrations)
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ProfessorId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProfessorThesisRegistration>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.ThesisRegistration)
        .WithMany(t => t.ProfessorThesisRegistrations)
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ThesisRegistrationId);
}
```

What do I need to change, so this relationship works? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I wanna go straight to the point I should say that You are **completely** wrong in designing your database because, with that scenario that you define, the relation between `Registrations` and `Professors` is not Many-To-Many, rather it is a One-To-Many relation.

*P.S: For Being tangible I add some property to your model.*

so for resolving your problem, act like below:

```
public class ThesisRegistration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int FirstExaminerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Professor FirstExaminer { get; set; }

    public int SecondExaminerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Professor SecondExaminer { get; set; }
}
```

and change **Professor** Model like below:

```
    public class Professor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ThesisRegistration> ThesisRegistrationsOfFirstExaminer { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ThesisRegistration> ThesisRegistrationsOfSecondExaminer { get; set; }
    }
```

and in the **OnModelCreating** Method:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ThesisRegistration>()
            .HasOne(p => p.FirstExaminer)
            .WithMany(p => p.ThesisRegistrationsOfFirstExaminer)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.FirstExaminerId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ThesisRegistration>()
            .HasOne(p => p.SecondExaminer)
            .WithMany(p => p.ThesisRegistrationsOfSecondExaminer)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.SecondExaminerId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

now with this design, every Thesis can have exactly two examiners, and each professor can have multiple theses.
feel free to ask questions. good luck.

Comment: gratified to hear.